# How do I force GRUB to keep video mode after switching to the OS?

Tags: boot, video, grub, bootloader

I use GRUB as a bootloader for my custom OS. I want it to enter graphics mode for me so I don’t have to do it myself in my system. However, before GRUB passes the control to the OS, video mode is changed back to 80x25 text mode. I have tried using `set gfxpayload=keep` but it doesn’t seem to do anything. The mode I chose (using set `gfxmode=1024x768x24`) works fine while GRUB is still active, but before passing the control to my OS’s entry point it goes back to text mode. Am I doing something wrong?
And, here is my `grub.cfg` file:

```
set root=(hd0,1)

set gfxmode=1024x768x24
set gfxpayload=keep

insmod vbe
insmod vga
insmod video_cirrus
insmod gfxterm

set menu_color_normal=red/blue
set menu_color_highlight=green/blue

loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2

terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm

set timeout=1
set default=0

menuentry "Trolololo" {
    multiboot /kernel
    boot
}
```

Comment: No, it is not Linux based (nor Linux compatible). It's a hobby OS written by me from the scratch. But that should not make any difference.

Comment: GRUB is Open Source, so if you can write your own OS, then you should be able to analyze the GRUB source code to determine where the video mode switching is performed.

Comment: I will have to, if I won't find any better solution, but that will be probably a mess. I mean... there has to be a better/correct way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. As sawdust suggested, analysing GRUB's source code was a way to go (`grub_multiboot_set_console` function in `grub-2.00/grub-core/loader/multiboot.c` file).

The problem was that my kernel is loaded by `multiboot <filename>` command and linux is loaded (in most cases) by `linux <filename>` command. Multiboot specification requires that information about preferred video mode is provided in the multiboot header. If that information is not provided, GRUB switches back to the text mode before starting the kernel and completely ignores `gfxpayload` variable.